# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [[Ljava.lang.String;]

Tags: xml, spring

Anyone help me please.
My project used hibernate 3.5 and spring 3.0.1 framework. 
I could not run my project 
i deployed my project on tomcat server 7.
I met the issue:

ERROR LOG:

```
     Apr 14, 2014 8:11:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
        SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ticketRegistry' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/ticketRegistry.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [[Ljava.lang.String;]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
            .................................................................
    org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:62)
            org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [[Ljava.lang.String;]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
            ... 32 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [[Ljava.lang.String;]
            at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.determineCollectionType(AttributeFactory.java:875)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:739)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:720)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:515)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:90)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:183)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.buildMetamodel(MetamodelImpl.java:66)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:83)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:850)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
            ... 39 more
Apr 14, 2014 8:11:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

deployerConfigContext.xml

```
...................

    <bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.JpaServiceRegistryDaoImpl"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

        <!-- This is the EntityManagerFactory configuration for Hibernate -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://10.61.203.192:3306/casDb?autoReconnect=true"
        p:username="username"
        p:password="password"
         />      
</beans>
```

**ticketRegistry.xml**

```
   ................................

    <!-- Ticket Registry -->
    <bean id="ticketRegistry" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JpaTicketRegistry">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!--Quartz -->
    <!-- TICKET REGISTRY CLEANER -->
    <bean id="ticketRegistryCleaner" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner"
          p:ticketRegistry-ref="ticketRegistry" />


    <bean id="cleanerLock"
          class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.JdbcLockingStrategy"
          p:uniqueId="${host.name}"
          p:platform="${ticket.cleaner.database.platform}"
          p:applicationId="cas-ticket-registry-cleaner"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
  />

    <bean id="ticketRegistryCleanerJobDetail"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean"
          p:targetObject-ref="ticketRegistryCleaner"
          p:targetMethod="clean"
  />

    <bean id="periodicTicketRegistryCleanerTrigger"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean"
          p:jobDetail-ref="ticketRegistryCleanerJobDetail"
          p:startDelay="20000"
          p:repeatInterval="1800000"
  />
</beans>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: Do you have the complete stack trace of that exception? Also, the definition of the 'ticketRegistry' bean?

Comment: Hi Andrei Stefan, thanks your comment.I added ticketRegistry.xml file. Do you have any solutions for my issue.

Comment: Can you, also, post the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Hi Andrei Stefan, Thanks for your kindness. I eddited my question. You know, stackoverflow's policy don't allow to post something having 5000 characters. So, do you need more information?

Comment: Are there any lines in the stack trace after `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [[Ljava.lang.String;]`? If there are, please post all of them.

Comment: Hi Andrei Stefan, I updated my question. Can you find out something on it? By the way, let me know your email i will send full log file to you :). Thanks your support again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the stack-trace, there is an error that starts somewhere from your persistence.xml file, I believe. The error is either in persistence.xml itself, in one of the entity files or maybe in the orm mapping file. You would need to show us the persistence.xml file.
For a complete stack trace, or better yet, for a complete log file, you could use [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and provide here the url it gives you.

Comment: Dear Andrei Stefan,
This is full serverlog file: http://pastebin.com/68T8HRWx
persistence.xml: http://pastebin.com/mCfhMGXz
Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to implement [this](https://wiki.jasig.org/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=11108686)?

Comment: Yes, I executed follow the guide: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/JpaTicketRegistry
It's not important. Their content is similiar. 
I apttempt to use JpaTicketRegistry for my project.
When i run on Tomcat Server, although tables were created, i cant deploy my project. The console always thrown out the error :(

Comment: I was asking about that guide, because I've tried the setup locally and I hit several issues with the third party libraries where, depending on the version, I got a different set of exceptions/behavior. For example, some versions of cas-server-core jar have the `JpaTicketRegistry` class without a constructor. Also, different behavior with Hibernate versions. I've tried some local setups and I didn't encounter the exception you get. And I used your exact configuration (copy-paste). Another difference is that I didn't test in a web app, just standalone.

Comment: Yes, i also dont know that is why. Everything was ok when i try deploying the example in the guide: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/End-to-end+Windows+Example
Tables would be created, data would be inserted, no exception.Then, I update all configuration, libraries(cas sever 3.4.2.1, spring3.0.1) to my project, i always met the error. It's so bad.
If i cant solved this error, i have to merger and update my porject follow the example which deployed successfully.
Thanks you very much :)

Comment: Even with cas 3.4.2.1 and Spring 3.0.1 I can't make it to break. Sorry.